# Internal server error when using certain locators in selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, internal-server-error

Whenever I try to locate an element that does not have an id but a lass instead I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Internal server error w
hile executing POST request at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/7bc6d0a9-2fd
a-4e4e-8c8e-751f50c156a1/element. Response: NULL
```

Now, I tried calling the class with 2 different methods:

```
$element = $this->byClassName('theClass');
//AND    
$element = $this->byCssSelector('theClass');
```

I also get the same error when using xPath, I don't know why this happens and would appreciate anyone who would have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I've been able to fix it, but the fix doesn't make any sense to me.  What I changed was selecting the absolute XPath instead of the relative XPath.

I can't think of any reason why that should work when selecting the relative XPath doesn't, and I know it's bad practice to select the absolute XPath, but there you go.  I'd be interested to see if this works for you as well.